# Graph Processing Algorithms by maxdemarzi, mvn clean package error

Tags: maven, neo4j, graph-databases, pagerank

I am working to find out noderanks from a neo4j database. For the same I am trying to use Graph processing algorithm by @maxdemarzi which has been explained in the link https://github.com/maxdemarzi/graph_processing . The version of neo4j which I am using is 3.0. When I am trying to do mvn clean package, the command throws the following error :
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project graph-processing: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.maxdemarzi:graph-processing:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT, org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:tests:2.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT in neo4j (http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots) -> [Help 1].

I did change neo4j version to 3.0 in pom.xml but the error is still the same. Kindly suggest a way to get rid of this error

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the project to use the latest version of Neo4j (3.0.4). Update your repository and try again... but this code has also been merged into Neo4j APOC. 
See https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/ . I recommend you look into using that instead which has a ton of functionality and is actively supported.

Regards,
Max

Comment: Hi Max, 
Thanks for your response. I looked into above mentioned link and again with mvn clean install, it gave error as there is no pom file in neo4j-apoc-procedures. But then I followed instructions mentioned in the link https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures and this seems to work. Thanks again.